# Using an iFrame to src locally-hosted content, is this safe and "correct" or should I use a different method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I'm working on a little project, and have attempted to "embed" (or otherwise) the mChat plugin from phpBB into the entirety of my website. After trying and failing to get the chat onto an external PHP page that I could simply include into my index, I settled for an iFrame with the following properties. The page mchat is hosted locally and is a page with my forums background, and the mchat module on it, afaik everything is served with https using letsencrypt (I don't receive any SSL errors anyway)...

```
    <div id="mchatdiv">
    <iframe scrolling="no" id="mchatframe" src="/path/to/forum/app.php/mchat">
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#mchatdiv {box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid rgb(5, 180, 1); overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;}
#mchatframe {transform: scale(1.052); border: 0px none; margin-top: -80px; margin-bottom: -125px; width: 100%; height: 500px;}
```

It took a long long time of modifying the mchat_body.html file, and modifying the iFrame CSS to get it right, but now it sits in my page "perfectly" on Firefox, Chrome and IE11.

Here's the issue, I started researching how to include a "Chat loading" section into the div while the frame is loading, and found a lot of scary pages about iFrames, and the vulnerabilities they open you up to, and how they should never used. I then tried to find everything I could about iFrames. And no matter where you look, there doesn't seem to be anything concrete.

Here on stackoverflow alone, you can find multiple examples of top-rated answers ranging from "if the content of the iFrame is locally hosted then you're not any more or less secure than you would be" to "iframes always increase your risks of XSS(?) attacks and..."

I'm sorry if it's not as simple a question as it seems to me, but am I opening my site up to any more vulnerabilities by using an iframe sourced to locally-hosted content? And if yes, can somebody please explain to me how so, and how I should go about retrieving this content for use on my page instead? I looked into jquery, but am hesitant to include the library for 'one task' - Is javascript capable of somehow doing the task more securely than an iFrame?

Thank you all very much for your time.

Comment: I've used `iframes` in the past and have never run into any attacks. https://iframely.com/ is worth checking out and it has an api which you can use for the development of your chat app.

Comment: Good stuff there cheers. The iFrame looking so nice now even if there is a "better way" I don't know I want it. I am very very annoyed with the way the iframe reloads every page load though (I thought I had a "dynamic webpage" in PHP but apparently I do not), so I'm in the process of trying to convert my website to ajax with jquery to solve this problem. So far, no luck haha. if I understand it right, wrap my body up in a div, use the document.ready function to call a page into it then use the loadContent, and ShowNewContent fucntions to change pages. My PHP backend is causing problems I think